# The usage of article

Tags: articles, conjunction-reduction

I want to ask a question of sentence usage.

Now assume there are two fruits in a basket, that is, one apple and one banana.

Here, I want to describe this scenario by the following sentence:

"There are an apple and a banana in the basket."

or

"There are an apple and banana in the basket" (That is to omit the article "a" before the word banana.)

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: First, you mean one should assume two **pieces** of fruit, not “two fruits”.   *Fruit* is generally received as a mass noun by native speakers, not a count noun. There are exceptions, but this doesn’t seem like one of them. Second, you mean “article usage”.  You cannot say “The usage of article” as you have, because you have in fact forgotten an article.

Comment: The 2nd is strange, it sounds like some combined fruit.